# How to show all data via has_many and belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have two models: Car and Engine.
One Car must have one engine.

My model associations

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :engine

  attr_accessible :name, :engine_id              
end
```

and

```
class Engine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars

  attr_accessible :name
end
```

I know how to show Engine data via Car:

```
Car.first.engine
```

This returns

```
irb(main):001:0> Car.first.engine
  ←[1m←[36mCar Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mEngine Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "engines".* FROM "engines" WHERE "engines"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<Engine id: 1, name: "Benzine", created_at: "2012-11-27 12:09:08", updated_at: "2012-11-27 12:09:08">
```

But how to show car and engine together?

Sample:
car_id: 1, car_name: Audi, engine_name: Benzine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Car.joins(:engine).includes(:engine).select("cars.name, engines.name")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 res = Car.joins(:engine).select("cars.id,cars.name,cars.model,engines.id,engines.name,...")
```

Comment: Car.joins(:engine).select("cars.id, cars.model_id, engines.id,engines.name")
  Car Load (1.0ms)  SELECT cars.id, cars.model_id, engines.id,engines.name FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "engines" ON "engines"."id" = "cars"."engine_id"
=> [#<Car id: 1, model_id: 1>]

Answer (score 1):

i'd say the easiest solution would be to create a custom method in your models. for example, in your car model (car.rb), you could try this:

```
  def info
    # as a string
    return "car: " + self.name + ", engine: " + self.engine.name
    # as a hash
    return { "car" => self.name, "engine" => self.engine.name }
  end
```

then you'd be able to call Car.first.info

Comment: I would like to get a SQL-table. Analogue in SQL - inner join